# Getting elements on page to reset to default size after font increase/decrease

Tags: jquery

How do I get the elements on my page to reset back to default after font increase/decrease

I've tried the following but with little success (font increase/decrease works):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3NGU/6/)

Here is my code:

```
$(".resetFont").click(function () {
});

$(".increaseFont").click(function () {
    var fontSize = getFontSize();
    var newFontSize = fontSize + 1;
    setFontSize(newFontSize);
    return false;
});

$(".decreaseFont").click(function () {
    var fontSize = getFontSize();
    var newFontSize = fontSize - 1;
    setFontSize(newFontSize);
    return false;
});

function getFontSize() {
    var currentSize = $("html").css("font-size");
    var currentSizeNumber = parseFloat(currentSize, 12);
    if (currentSizeNumber > 24) {
        currentSizeNumber = 24;
    }
    if (currentSizeNumber < 10) {
        currentSizeNumber = 10;
    }
    return currentSizeNumber;
}

function setFontSize(size) {
    $("html").css("font-size", size);
    $(".actualSize").html(size);
}
```

Comment: What is the `12` supposed to be in `parseFloat(currentSize, 12);`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var defaultFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');

$(".resetFont").click(function () {
    $('html').css('font-size', defaultFontSize);
});
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R3NGU/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var defaultFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
$(".resetFont").click(function () {

$("html").css("font-size", defaultFontSize);
    $(".actualSize").html(defaultFontSize );


});
```

Comment: What is `size`? and why do you set html content to `.actualSize`

Comment: @gdoron This was in the OP's post and seems to be an element that indicated the font size and needs to be updated when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just set what you want the original font size to be:

```
 $(".resetFont").click(function () {
      $("html").css("font-size", '24px');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.resetFont').click(function(){
    setFontSize('auto');
}
```

Really no one got this?